# WP8 Can't show listbox item after using hardware back button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have two `ListBox` items: one for show all items and another `ListBox` for show only selected item and now when I am using hardware back button second `ListBox` item is not showing?

What do I need to do to allow the `ListBox` to be selectable/clickable upon return?

```
Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtMSG" Text="TextBox" Width="456"/>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,10,15,0">
            <ListBox Name="list_location" Tap="list_location_Tap" Foreground="Black">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>

            <ListBox Name="list_locationAdd"  Foreground="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

list_locationAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
list_location.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

if (!list_locationAdd.Items.Contains(list_location.SelectedItem))
{
    list_locationAdd.Items.Add(list_location.SelectedItem);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the first listbox should have focus after you press back button?

Comment: Sir  Jon Koivula,actually i am using location api when user will search related data is show on first list box and then i choose a single item in first list box and display selected item in second listbox thats working fine now when i will back on my app  i want to show second listbox with item when i reopen my app?

Comment: I'm guessing that you will have to save your items to XML File or something. Its not saving your listbox items after you go back to your app.

Comment: sir  Jon Koivula you are right but how i can save my list box item in windows phone i have try to save in isolated storage but its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Create XML document and save it to your phone using StorageFile class. Everytime you open your app, it will on launch check your xml file and populate the datagrid. So when you make changes to listboxes it should make changes to xml file too. Next time you quit your application and launch it again, reads data from xml file and then it has the data as it was last time. So my answer is: save your data on phone with xml file.

Save data to phone: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx

Handling XML documents and elements: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: sir i am trying to save xml file but i am getting error to save it ?

Comment: Whats the error? I cant help if i dont know details

Comment: Hello  Jon Koivula sir Thanks for your help i have solve my problem but sir now i am facing one more problem i am not able to save all selected item

Comment: How you are not able to save? Did you go through all items like this foreach(Listboxitem item in list_locationAdd.Items){ //save your items values to Xelements and in the end save them to XDocument and save it to file }

Comment: Sir  Jon Koivula  i have save item in successfully. but now the problem is when i come back my app and select another list box item the previous item is removed from the xml file and list box also and new item is add instead of previous item.