# How to Add Show and Hide Button with Image in Listbox item in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have a listbox with some contact number in listbox now i want to add Show and Hide button to each of contact item in list box when user press Hide button contact will be Hide and when user press Show button contact will be show and vise versa how i can do this in WP8..
i am using following code please help me..

```
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource kconverter}}"  Width="48" Height="48" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="355, 0, 0, 0">
                                <Image Name="onimg" Visibility="Visible" Source="/Assets/Images/blue.button.png"  Width="85" Height="20" Tap="Image_TapOn" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Border>

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="355, 0, 0, 0">
                                <Image Name="offimg" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="/Assets/Images/setting-h.png" Width="85" Height="48" Tap="Image_TapOff" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Border>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use this code Hope so it works for you.
**Note : Bind only ObservableCollection to ListBox to Use INotifyPropertyChanged**

**XAML :**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">

        <ListBox x:Name="lstContact">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border  Background="#404040"
                                 Height="45"
                                 Width="60"
                                 Tag="{Binding ContactId}"
                                 Tap="_Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="-"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       Foreground="White" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Name="BrCount"
                                Width="160"
                                Height="45"
                                BorderBrush="#404040"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Margin="10,0">
                            <TextBlock Name="LblCont"
                                       Text="{Binding ContactName}"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       Foreground="#404040"
                                       Visibility="{Binding _Visibility}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#404040"
                                Height="45"
                                Width="60"
                                Tag="{Binding ContactId}"
                                Tap="_Visible">
                            <TextBlock Text="+"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       Foreground="White" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

**C# :**

```
private ObservableCollection<Contact> _contact = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        _contact = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _contact.Add(new Contact() { ContactId = i, ContactName = "Name " + i, _Visibility = Visibility.Visible });
        }
        lstContact.ItemsSource = _contact;
    }

    private void _Collapsed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Border bdr = (Border)sender;
        _contact.Where(X => X.ContactId == Convert.ToInt32(bdr.Tag.ToString())).First()._Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void _Visible(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Border bdr = (Border)sender;
        _contact.Where(X => X.ContactId == Convert.ToInt32(bdr.Tag.ToString())).First()._Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        public Visibility _visibility;

        public Visibility _Visibility
        {
            get { return _visibility; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _visibility, value); }
        }

        protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(storage, value))
            {
                storage = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: sir i have one more problem i want to add one list box selected item to please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844360/wp8-cant-show-listbox-item-after-using-hardware-back-button